# Facebook dialog share (redirect_uri URL is not properly formated

Tags: facebook, dialog, share

I have done a huge amount of research regarding this issue but non of the answers worked for me. 
I have created my facebook app and got the APP-ID now when I am constructing the URL to share a test image on facebook wall I keep getting this error

**This dialog has been passed a bad parameter.**
**API Error Code: 100**
**API Error Description: Invalid parameter**
**Error Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted**

My constructed URL is

www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=' + '[MYAPPID]' + '&display=popup&caption=Check out this picture' + '&link=' + '[MYAPP].herokuapp.com/assets/wolf-391302847666d53202dab51e1ea4d8a8.jpg' + '&redirect_uri=' + '[MYAPP].herokuapp.com/' + '&picture=' + '[MYAPP].herokuapp.com/assets/wolf-391302847666d53202dab51e1ea4d8a8.jpg' + '&name=' + 'wolf' + '&description=' + 'wolf_description'

As it was prompted in one of the answers, I have created a website platform in my facebook app and added

[MYAPP].herokuapp.com/ to both site URL and APP domains.

I am also getting a warning while using an facebook debugger toll although I don't believe this causes the problem

**he 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.**

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Show us the actual, final URL, instead of something with placeholders in it.

Comment: Hi @CBroe. That is the actual URL, instead of [MYAPPID] I am using the APPID facebook had provided and instead of MYAPP I am using the APPname heroku had provided. I strongly believe it is not the best practice to share confidential information in public. If there is anything else you can see and point me towards, I would appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I was having a type. Sorry for the false alarm.
Cheers.